# selecting all fields into two different table with same id_ref

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables. salessumarry and rsales . both table have common id_ref. so what i am trying to get is select all those values from rsales and salessumarry has the same id_ref. here is my code so far.  but this is not running. i don't know what's the problem with this.

```
$result1 = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
    salessumarry,rsales.*,
    FROM salessumarry
    LEFT JOIN rsales ON rsales.receipt = salessumarry.receipt 
    WHERE (register_mode='sales') AND (date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b')GROUP BY receipt");
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo on here.. But you have an extra comma after `rsales.*` which shouldn't be there... When you say not running. What exactly do you mean? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

You are using extra comma Please see this Query and test.

```
SELECT 
  salessumarry,
  rsales.*
FROM
  salessumarry 
  LEFT JOIN rsales 
    ON rsales.receipt = salessumarry.receipt 
WHERE (register_mode = 'sales') 
  AND (DATE BETWEEN '$a' 
    AND '$b') 
GROUP BY receipt
```

Answer (score 0):

if want all fields

```
 SELECT 
    salessumarry,rsales.*, 
 FROM
```

should be

```
 SELECT 
    * 
 FROM
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are using table name instead of column name in your select query for `salessumarry` and there is an extra comma after `rsales.*`. I suppose you are trying to do  something like this:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
    salessumarry.*,rsales.*
    FROM salessumarry
    LEFT JOIN rsales ON rsales.receipt = salessumarry.receipt 
    WHERE (register_mode='sales') AND (date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b')GROUP BY salessumarry.receipt");
```

**Note:**
Please avoid using [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) as

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

1. As documented under [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

   > #### Warning
   >
   > This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
   >
   > - [mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
   > - [PDO::query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

   Therefore, you *really* should switch to a different API.
2. As also documented:

   > #### Return Values
   >
   > For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, **mysql_query()** returns a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) on success, or **`FALSE`** on error.
   >
   > `[ deletia ]`
   >
   > #### Example #1 Invalid Query
   >
   > The following query is syntactically invalid, so **mysql_query()** fails and returns **`FALSE`**.
   >
   > ```php
   > <?php
   > $result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
   > if (!$result) {
   >     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
   > }
   >
   > ?>
   > ```

   Therefore, if you *don't* switch to using a different API, you should *at least* test the value of `$result1` and, if it's `FALSE`, inspect [`mysql_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) for further information on what went wrong.
3. Even if you *don't* do either of the above, you could output `mysql_query()`'s string argument to see exactly what command is being sent to the MySQL server; and then try copying/pasting that into a MySQL client (in order that you can directly inspect how the server responds).
4. In the absence of any of the above steps, it is difficult for anyone here to tell you exactly what the problem might be.  However, my guess is that there are *at least* three problems:

   - you have a superfluous comma at the end of your `SELECT` list;
   - you do not have a *column* named `salessumarry`, which appears in the `SELECT` list; and
   - the `receipt` column on which you are grouping your query is ambiguous (there appears to be such a named column in both tables)—you should *qualify* the column reference with a table identifier.
5. You should also read the article [MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-extensions.html), since even when the above problems are corrected you probably will have a query that returns indeterminate results (which is unlikely to be your intention).